# Choose between 手数料 vs キャンセル料

Tags: word-choice

Which one is used in the context of hotels, attractions, and so on (reservations)?

Is there a better word to say it?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, a 手数料 does not necessarily imply a cancellation of anything...

Comment: What are you referring to by *it* ? > Is there a better word to say it?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. My English is also not perfect. Im talking about the fee you have to pay if you make a reservation and cancel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean cancellation fee, then it is キャンセル料.

手数料 is transaction fee of any kind. E.g., you withdraw money from bank, you may be charged a small fee as 手数料.

Comment: Thank you very much!